# Clear half of the screen from the command-line

Tags: terminal, tput

Is there some way clear the terminal but instead of leaving the prompt at the top of the screen leaves it in the middle?  It looks like `clear` basically ignores all command-line parameters.

I thought there would be some way to do this with `tput` but can't find one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use `tput` to move the cursor to a given line in the screen, e.g.,

```
tput cup 11 0
```

to move it to the twelfth line (values count from zero).

Along the same lines, you could use `tput` to clear from that position to the end of the screen, using the `ed` capability.  Combining,

```
tput cup 11 0 && tput ed
```

might be what was wanted.

If you want to go to the halfway mark on the screen, the first number returned by

```
stty size
```

is (on most systems) the number of rows of the screen.  Adding that to the command:

```
tput cup $(stty size|awk '{print int($1/2);}') 0 && tput ed
```

The `clear` program differs from `tput ed`:

- it moves the cursor to the *home* position (upper left) and
- clears from that point to the end of the screen.

Caveat: on some platforms [**`tput ed`**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552845/tput-ed-is-empty/556123#556123) may not work due to problems fixed long ago.  In those cases, upgrading your curses/ncurses configuration will fix the problem.

Comment: on unix, this doesn't clear the text for me, but does move the cursor

Comment: Sounds like a bug fixed ten years ago.  Perhaps time to upgrade things.

Answer (score 2):

Refering [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1579391/673470)

```
# Get ceiling eg: 7/2 = 4
ceiling_divide() {
  ceiling_result=$((($1+$2-1)/$2))
}

clear_rows() {
  POS=$1
  # Insert Empty Rows to push & preserve the content of screen
  for i in {1..$((LINES-POS-1))}; echo
  # Move to POS, after clearing content from POS to end of screen
  tput cup $((POS-1)) 0
}

# Clear quarter
alias ptop='ceiling_divide $LINES 4; clear_rows $ceiling_result'
# Clear half
alias pmid='ceiling_divide $LINES 2; clear_rows $ceiling_result'
# Clear 3/4th
alias pdown='ceiling_divide $((3*LINES)) 4; clear_rows $ceiling_result'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the line count is odd then `tput cup` clears the whole page.
writing it like this should fix that:

```
tput cup $(($(stty size|awk '{print $1}')/2)) 0 && tput ed
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're interested in clearing the *bottom* half of the screen while maintaining the rest, then this will work:

```
half=$(stty size | awk '{print int($1/2)-1;}'); for i in `seq ${half}`; do echo '' ; done && tput cup ${half} 0 && tput ed
```

EDIT: To clarify, if you run `seq $(stty size | cut -d' ' -f1)` the other answers will leave the first half of the output, while this command will leave the second half (i.e. the most recent output).