# tput ed is empty

Tags: tput, terminfo, macos

The output of `tput ed` is empty and I can't figure out why. Other capabilities work fine. Also `ed` is not missing from `infocmp` output so tput should match, right?

```
$ printf '%q' "$(tput ed)"
''
```

```
$ printf '%q' "$(tput home)"
$'\033'\[H
```

I'm using zsh on Mac OS 10.14.6 and iTerm2. TERM=xterm-256color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After more googling and scouring the documentation (mainly terminfo), I finally figured out that I need to fall back to the older **termcap** code since the **capname** is not supported for all terminfo capabilities.

```
ed=$(tput ed || tput cd)
```

Answer (score 6):

Apple configured ncurses with termcap support (in addition to the default terminfo):

- [config.status](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ncurses/ncurses-53.200.3/ncurses/config.status.auto.html) file showing the configure options.
- infocmp calls [_nc_read_file_entry](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ncurses/ncurses-53/ncurses/progs/infocmp.c.auto.html) to obtain its data.
- tput calls [setupterm](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ncurses/ncurses-53/ncurses/ncurses/tinfo/lib_setup.c.auto.html), which goes to **`_nc_read_entry`**, which calls **`_nc_read_tic_entry`**, which does call **`_nc_read_file_entry`**
- if there's a problem in **`_nc_read_tic_entry`**, then **`_nc_read_entry`** falls back to the termcap support (see [**`read_entry.c`**](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ncurses/ncurses-53/ncurses/ncurses/tinfo/read_entry.c.auto.html)).

Since that's ten-year-old code, the possible problem in _nc_read_tic_entry may have been fixed a while back.

For instance, I have MacPorts installed, and that works properly, while Apple's version does not.  Here is a top-level script that I used to investigate the problem with:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset TERMINFO
unset TERMINFO_DIRS
export TERM=xterm-256color
#export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
echo TERMCAP
infocmp -CrTt1 | grep -E ':..=.*:' | sed -e 's/^    ://' -e 's/=.*//' | xargs -n 1 /tmp/test-tput
echo TERMINFO
infocmp -1 | grep -E '^ .*=.*,' | sed -e 's/^   //' -e 's/=.*//' | xargs -n 1 /tmp/test-tput
```

(commenting/uncommenting the `PATH` to select between the two), and that called a second script **`/tmp/test-tput`** to show the values:

```
#!/bin/bash
tput "$1" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null || exit
echo -n "CAP:$1 "
tput "$1" 2>/dev/null
echo
```

The behavior in ncurses 5.7 was a bug introduced in [1999](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t990123)

```
    + modify tput to accept termcap names as an alternative to terminfo
      names (patch by Jeffrey C Honig).
```

and fixed in [2009](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20091227):

```
    + change order of lookup in progs/tput.c, looking for terminfo data
      first.  This fixes a confusion between termcap "sg" and terminfo
      "sgr" or "sgr0", originally from 990123 changes, but exposed by
      20091114 fixes for hashing.  With this change, only "dl" and "ed" are
      ambiguous (Mandriva #56272).
```

Apple's [ncurses 5.7](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20081102) is about a year older than that fix.